# coefficients of product of polynomials proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If 
$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}x^{i}$ and 
$g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{m}b_{i}x^{i}$ are two polynomials of degree n and m respectively their product is defined by $f(x)+g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{m+n}c_{i}x^{i}$ where  $c_{k}=a_{0}b_{k}+a_{1}b_{k-1}+\cdot \cdot \cdot +a_{k-1}b_{1}+a_{k}b_{0}$ are the coefficients of the new polynomial. How to prove that this holds for every coefficient of the new polynomial?

Answer (score 2):

If you really mean the product, use cdot as sign.

$\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}x^{i}\cdot \sum_{i=0}^{m}b_{i}x^{i}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{m}a_{i}b_{j}x^{i+j}$.

now define $k=i+j$ and sort by equal powers.